# Does apache or nginx must be installed before I can run my PHP files in browser?

Tags: php

Does apache or nginx must be installed before I can run my PHP files in browser?
Django itself has a run-server for testing python codes.Is there any similar way to test PHP files?

Comment: The new version of PHP 5.4 has a test server you can use - http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: If you're starting out, stick with Apache to start off with. There's a great deal more support/advice for it around - switch to nginx later once you get comfy, and if you need to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Your options is:

- Install web server, as you said.
- Use [web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), as JohnP suggested.
- Install php-cli, run your script from console, save output to html file and open it in a browser.

Actually, you can't normally "run" php files in browser. Browser can only send requests to server and display script's output.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [built in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) from php 5.4.

Before PHP 5.4 you must install a web server to execute php files in browser

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need something like nginx or Apache.  Either install one of those (on say your local machine).  **OR**, see JohnP's comment - a new feature released recently.